# Library, “Injecting factory” and best practices for extending a library

Tags: java, design-patterns, dependency-injection, factory, architectural-patterns

I use a library which I need to patch. I need to fork it because Factory design patter is not used.

Library has that structure: class X that hold references to other classes, that hold references to other classes and few more layers. Class hierarchy is “tree-like” structure.

I look for best way for refactoring – flexible enough to prevent people forking it. I cannot find any best practices on that problem.

Over years I use to solve it by “Injecting Factory” – Factory pattern where parent object is being injected (DI) in factory method. I cannot find any documentation on such approach and I need some feedback on it (e.g. theory or possible problems).

I describe it with an example with Car:

- Car has CarInterior
- CarInterior has Odometer

Problem – no custom objects could be created, especially Odometer.

```
class Car {
  CarInterior interior;
  public Car() {
    interior = new CarInterior();
  }
}
class CarInterior {
  Odometer odo;
  public CasInterior(){
    odo = new Odomether();
  }
}
class Odometer {
  public Odometer(){}
}
```

## By-book solution using simple Factory methods pattern only (has a limited extendibility)

```
class Car {
  CarInterior interior;
  public Car(CarFactory factory) {
    interior = createInterior();
  }
  CarInterior createInterior() { return new CarInterior(); };
}
class CasInterior {
  Odometer odo;
  public CarInterior(){
    odo = createOdometer();
  }
  CarInterior createOdometer() {
    return new Odomether();
  }
}
```

### Major problem with this approach

- If factory method needs parameters, that change potentially makes troubles to lib users. Because extending classes should change method definitions.

### Minor problems

- if I need to different Odometer, I should extend both Car and CarInterior
- library I need to fork has few “levels” so this means many levels of extra objects till I manage to call The factory method.

## Possible Business requests

### Possible extension #1 of Odometer class: with KM or Miles

Car object should have targetCountry. If it is in France, Metric units should be used. If in USA – miles.
That business request could be implemented in this way:

- (breaking change) factory method createOdometer() gets a param: createOdometer(OdoUnits)
- (breaking change) factory method createInterior() gets a param: createInterior(OdoUnits) or createInterior(Country)
- in case of more levels (my case), more changes are needed

### Possible extension #2 of Odometer class: odometer values range

- 0-220 km/h
- 0-300 km/h
- etc

### Possible extension #3 of Odometer class: color of odometer should be same as color of the car

If we use same approach, we should introduce more parameters in methods. And more “proxy” functionality.

## Questions

So what are best practices for the issue? How could we avoid/reduce method definitions changes while new requirements come?

Answer (score 0):

## "Injecting Factory"

- Factory methods takes an additional parameter – parent object.
- Odometer gets its Factory, gets Car object and requests all needed data to adapt to the "Car specs"

CODE:

```
class CarFactory {
  CarInterior createInterior(Car car) { return new CarInterior(car); }
  Odometer createOdometer(CarInterior interior){ return new Odometer(interior); };
}
class Car {
  CarFactory factory;
  CarInterior interior;
  public Car(CarFactory factory) {
    this.factory = factory;
    interior = factory.createInterior(this);
  }
  CarFactory getFactory(){ return factory; };
}
class CarInterior {
  Car car;
  Odometer odo;
  public CarInterior(Car car){
    this.car = car;
    CarFactory factory = car.getFactory();
    odo = factory.createOdometer( this );
  }
}
class Odometer {
  public Odometer(CarInterior interior) {
    Car car = interior.getCar();
    OdoUnits odoUnits = car.getTargetCountry().getUnits();
    int maxEngineSpeed = car.getEngine().getTopSpeed;
    Color color = car.getColor();
    if (!car.isOptionColorOdometer())
      color = DEFAULT_COLOR; 
    // etc
  }
}
```